# iPhone Animation view doesn't start from last point

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

iPhone app a `UIView` animation from top to some point in moves position in y axis 15 to 118 in below code

```
-(void) moveAndFlipAnimation33 {
     NSValue * from = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:15];
     NSValue * to = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:118];
     NSString * keypath = @"position.y";
     [self.summaryView.centerOvalView.layer addAnimation:[self bounceAnimationFrom:from to:to forKeyPath:keypath withDuration:1] forKey:@"bounce"];
     [self.summaryView.centerOvalView.layer setValue:to forKeyPath:keypath];
}

-(CABasicAnimation *)bounceAnimationFrom:(NSValue *)from to:(NSValue *)to   forKeyPath:(NSString *)keypath withDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration {
     CABasicAnimation * result = [CABasicAnimation  animationWithKeyPath:keypath];
     [result setFromValue:from];
     [result setToValue:to];
     [result setDuration:duration];
     [result setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction   functionWithControlPoints:1.0 :1.5 :.8 :0.8]];
     return  result;
 }
```

When animation starts, it shows complete view at 15 y position and goes to 118 but I want when animation start from view end position and slowly it show complete view (**example** same like sun set)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite get what you're asking. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: u can take a example of a man's pic while showing a animated pic of man from 15 y position to 118 y position  at present code set the whole pic from( man's head to leg ) on 15 position  and then animated but i want at the time of starting of animation  we shows last part of pic from (man's leg to head) and then start animation its shows like pic arise from that point .....